# Google Reader api mark all news from a specific source as read! I've the request

Tags: google-reader, http-post

Google Reader api mark all news from a specific source as read! I've sniffed the request but I can't understant which paramters it want's

This is the post

```
http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/mark-all-as-read?client=scroll
```

and all arguments are

```
s=user%2F1400000000005773457%2Flabel%2FCultura&t=Cultura&ts=1302000000000000772&T=%2F%2FRcaqdpNe_mDnkehf-L5af9w
```

NOTE: The Numeber like 14000000000057734... are not true...I masquerade it because I think they are sensible data.

My questions is can someone show me the correct request? Which are the correct parameters to do this post request?

The request that I show in this post works because I grab It from the Google Reader site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant parameters are:

1. `s`: The [stream](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/StreamId) you wish to mark all as read. The example you have is marking as read the user's "Cultura" label. To mark a feed you you use `feed/<feed url>`
2. `ts`: The timestamp (in microseconds) you wish to mark all as items as read to. This can be the current time (to mark all items), or a date in the past (e.g. to mark all items older than 1 week as read, use the current time minus 1 weeek.
3. `T`: The [action token](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/ActionToken) (necessary for all POST requests)